# Передача значения checkbox false

Tags: html, post, checkbox

Есть checkbox

```
input id="all" name="all[1]" type="checkbox">
```

Если выделено то возвращает

```
[all] => Array ( [1] => on )
```

А если не выделено, то он вообще ничего не передает, а нужно что бы передавал off или false или 0, без разницы, что бы он существовал в передаче значение через Post

Comment: Зачем такое требование?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
<input name="all[1]" type="hidden" value="off">
<input id="all" name="all[1]" type="checkbox">
```